# Storing unicode text in std:string

Tags: c++, stdstring, wstring

I have some server-side C# code that serializes (among other things) some Unicode strings (using UTF8 encoding).

On the client side, I would like to deserialize all these strings. I was able to deserialize them and store them as `wstring`s.

But then I've heard that Unicode strings can be stored in regular `string`s as well. I've also read that `wstring`s are not portable and should therefore be avoided. So I am wondering what are the benefits/drawbacks of using `string` vs. `wstring` in my situation.

Also, I still don't understand how is it possible to store Unicode strings inside of regular `string` variables. That sounds strange knowing that string is vector of chars. How can an arbitrary character be stored inside of a char (8-bit type)? Would `string::length()` return the number of characters or bytes? What about `string::size()?` What would the indexing operator return?

Comment: Why not spend some time googling around "UTF-8" and see what you learn?

Comment: UTF-8 encoding is identical to ASCII for codepoints between 0 and 127; higher codepoints are encoded in multiple bytes. So non-ASCII characters will encode as 2 or 3 bytes. String length counts non-zero bytes, not number of characters.

Comment: May be worth searching [tag:unicode] [tag:c++] std::string: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bunicode%5D+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+std%3A%3Astring+

Comment: Sad but true: Unicode support sucks in almost every language.

Comment: if you have `utf-8`  you can just use `std::string`, if of course you not need access to specific character by index

Comment: Ok, it looks like I can use a std::string, but none of its methods such as: length(), substr(), indexing operator, etc... will return desired result, so I don't get much by using std::string other than having a container to store those bytes. I guess, wstring is better option then, since at least it provides access and operations on individual characters.

Comment: We have an excellent question on this topic already. If there's anything missing in there, (and assuming it's not answered in another C++/Unicode question either), feel free to ask a new question. If you do, do reference the existing questions you already checked.